# How to check if a pandas column contain strings from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['containName'] = 0
for i in range (df2.shape[0]):
    df.loc[df['string'].str.contains(df2['name'][i],case=False), "containName"]=1
```

I am using the above code, but it takes a lot of time (my df contain millions of rows). Any vectorized fast solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can using

```
df['containName']=df['string'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['name']),case=False)
```

Comment: Any faster solution? I ran this line 10 mins go, still running.

Comment: Edit: Still running. DF has 2 million rows

Comment: Something it is wrong. It is returning true for most of the text. I did `print(df['string'].str.contains("|".join("sdfdfddsfdsffsdfsdfsdsfs"),case=False))`

Comment: and it returns true. Not even a single row contain that word.